# CloudFoundry UAA with Oracle DB

Tags: cloudfoundry-uaa

The supported databases listed in the UAA documentation seem to be MySQL, PostgresSQL and HSQL.

I noticed this pull request from 2013 which provided Oracle DB support for UAA - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/pull/39 but am unable to find any documentation related to UAA with Oracle DB

Has anyone used UAA with an Oracle DB ?

Answer (score 1):

We currently do not support Oracle. We picked three open source databases for this open source project to stick with and that way have somewhat manageable CI pipelines.

We would however consider contribution if there was a willingness to maintain it.